# Change Flip-switch background color programmatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a application for mobile with jQuery mobile and Phonegap. so my situation is i need to change the flip toggle buttons background color programmatically. 
eg: if the button is on the background color is green otherwise it goes red. how can i set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the css for your need

```
<style>
.ui-btn-active {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from( #44C723 ),to( #317220 ));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #44C723,#317220 );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( #44C723,#317220 );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( #44C723,#317220 );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( #44C723,#317220 );
  background-image: linear-gradient( #44C723,#317220 )
}
.ui-btn-down-e{
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from( #d2232b ),to( #d2232b ));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #d2232b,#d2232b );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( #d2232b,#d2232b );
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( #d2232b,#d2232b );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient( #d2232b,#d2232b );
  background-image: linear-gradient( #d2232b,#d2232b )

}
.online { color: yellow !important } // for changing text color
.offline { color: #fff !important } // for changing text color
</style>
```

Add some javascript

```
<script>
$('[role=application] span:first-child').addClass('online');
$('[role=application] span:nth-child(2)').addClass('offline');
</script>
```

This is your html

```
<div id="switch">
  <select name="toggleswitch1" id="toggleswitch1" data-track-theme="e" data-role="slider">
      <option value="off"> Offline </option>
      <option value="on"> Online </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here the .ui-btn-active,.ui-btn-down-e class in css is used to change the background color in different browsers you can change your color here if needed. the javascript is used to change the text color of online and offline.
Here is the example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunkumarthekkoot/95gPP/

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this simple style works for me:

**CSS part**

```
.ui-slider-track .ui-btn-active {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

For completeness of code, here are the remaining parts... 
**HTML part**

```
<label for="flipSwitch">On/Off</label>
<select name="flipSwitch" id="idFlipSwitch" data-role="slider">
    <option value="on">On</option>
    <option value="off">Off</option>
</select>
```

Finally the **jQuery part**

```
$("#idFlipSwitch").val("on").slider("refresh");
```

Comment: Do you know why? What's the markup? Additional information would improve your answer.

Comment: @dakab I've updated my post with the remaining pieces. Hope it is much clear now.

Answer (score -2):

```
 **CSS**
  <style>
            .green {
                background: green;
            }
            .red {
                background: red;
            }
  </style> 

  **html**
  <a href="" class="green" id="btn" data-role="none">Button</a>

   **Javascript**
  <script>
      $("#btn").on("click",function(){

        if($(this).hasClass("green")){
            $(this).removeClass("green");
            $(this).addClass("red");
            return;
        }if($(this).hasClass("red")){
            $(this).removeClass("red");
            $(this).addClass("green");
            return;
        }
      });

    </script>
```